# Не активен аккордион на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Всем привет!
Столкнулась с проблемой неработающего меню аккордион на странице(
Уже все перетыкала и так и этак подключала скрипты, но ничего не получается.
Хелп!

Так же не могу подключить Jquery UI с ее библиотеками чтобы сделать слайдер ползунок для указания цен в фильтре(

Вот ссылка на репо: https://github.com/Nibrodi/test-site

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Во первых, ты подключаешь скрипт в head, и тебе нужно пользоваться конструкцией:

```js
window.onload=()=>{/* code */};
```

Например запуск функции сюда можешь запихнуть или само тело, вообще евенты я бы в боди сувал, но если у тебя там логика визуала будет, то 1 секунду после ф5 у тебя будет кёк

Во вторых, JQuery вешает у тебя евент клика на `Батю`, а не детей `h1`

В третьих, подключать библиотеки нужно(имхо) так:

1. JQuery
2. Либы.js
3. Твой файл.js // Но его можно подключить в body(где у тебя `stepper.min.js` я обнаружил), чтобы не `Во первых`(в моём ответе)

В четвертых, придирки, `var \ this` уже устарели, да и структура `script.js` хромает, рекомендую читнуть про es6 на хабре есть пару статей да и [learn.js.com](https://learn.javascript.ru) никто не отменял